# Service data not being updated Angular

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-service

I have a Service whose method `getData(type)` is called everytime a controller loads. This function is supposed to update two objects `dealers` and `items` of it's own. These two objects are referenced by my controller to watch for changes and update the view accordingly but the `factory` variables never get updated and hence the view never get's populated. Here is my factory

```
    app.factory('LS', function($window) {
    var dealers=[];
    var items=[];
    console.log(this);
return {
    setData: function(type,val) {
        type=='dealers'?chrome.storage.local && chrome.storage.local.set('dealers', JSON.stringify(val)):chrome.storage.local && chrome.storage.local.set('items', JSON.stringify(val));
        return this;
    },
    getData: function(type) {
        if(type=='dealers'){
            chrome.storage.local && chrome.storage.local.get('dealers',function(result){
                if(Object.keys(result).length)
                {
                    this.dealers=result.dealers;
                }
                else{
                    var val=[{name:"name",id:5},{},...];
                chrome.storage.local && chrome.storage.local.set({'dealers': JSON.stringify(val)});
                chrome.storage.local && chrome.storage.local.get('dealers',function(result){
                    this.dealers=result.dealers;
                });
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            chrome.storage.local && chrome.storage.local.get('items',function(result){
                if(Object.keys(result).length)
                {
                    this.items=result.items;
                }
                else{
                    var val=[{name:"name",price:500,number:0},{},...];
                    chrome.storage.local && chrome.storage.local.set({'items': JSON.stringify(val)});
                    chrome.storage.local && chrome.storage.local.get('items',function(result){
                        this.items=result.items;
                    });
                }
            })
        }
    },
    dealers:dealers,
    items:items
};
  })
```

And here's my controller

```
    .controller('OrderCtrl', function($scope,$timeout, $stateParams,LS) {
    this.dealers=LS.dealers;
    this.itemslist=LS.items;
    LS.getData('dealers');
    LS.getData('items');
    $scope.resetitems=angular.copy($scope.itemslist);
    $scope.order={dealer:'',submissionDate:new Date()};
    $scope.resetorder=angular.copy($scope.order);
    $scope.doRefresh = function() {

        console.log('Refreshing!');
        $timeout( function() {
            //simulate async response
            $scope.dealers=LS.getData('dealers');
            $scope.itemslist = LS.getData('items');
            //Stop the ion-refresher from spinning
            $scope.$broadcast('scroll.refreshComplete');

        }, 1000);

    };
    $scope.sum = function() {
        var total=0;
        angular.forEach($scope.itemslist , function(item){
            //if(false)
            total=total+(item.data*item.number);
        });
        return total;
    }
    var ordered=[];
    $scope.submit=function(){
        angular.forEach($scope.itemslist , function(item){
            if(item.number>0)
            {
                ordered.push({'name':item.value,'pcs':item.number,'price':(item.data*item.number)});
            }
        });
        alert('You ordered '+ ordered);

        addOrder({"dealername":JSON.parse($scope.order.dealer).name,"dealerid":JSON.parse($scope.order.dealer).id,"date":$scope.order.submissionDate,"bill":$scope.sum(),"items":ordered});
        ordered=[];
        angular.copy($scope.resetorder,$scope.order);
        angular.copy($scope.resetitems,$scope.itemslist);
    }
     })
```

Comment: shouldn't the `getData()` calls come *before* the local assignment? also, you don't return anything in `getData`

Comment: I'm setting the service variable in getData() so I don't need to return anything, the controller and service must be in sync.

Comment: but if you do `JSON.parse(LS.getData('dealers'))`, what exactly do you expect to be parsed?

Comment: Oh that part is before I was using Chrome Local Storage API, I'm editing that.

Comment: you're still doing it in your `$timeout` callback

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies here
`chrome.storage.local && chrome.storage.local.get('dealers',function(result){ if(Object.keys(result).length) { this.dealers=result.dealers; } else{ var val=[{name:"name",id:5},{},...]; chrome.storage.local && chrome.storage.local.set({'dealers': JSON.stringify(val)}); chrome.storage.local && chrome.storage.local.get('dealers',function(result){ this.dealers=result.dealers; }); }`

In the controller I am assigning the dealers in the controller to the dealers in the factory and then in the factory, I change the reference of dealers so the dealers in the controller are pointing to a previous memory location and the dealers in the factory are now pointing to the new memory location.
The solution is to not change the factory variable reference.
Must be careful with JavaScript from now on